# If $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n =a$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} (x_n - y_n) =0$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n =a$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I guess I get the gist of the idea but I don't know how to write it rigorously, I know that we have:

- For all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $n_0 \in N$ such that if $n>n_0$, then $|x_n - a| <\epsilon$.
- For all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $n_0 \in N$ such that if $n>n_0$, then $|x_n - y_n - 0| <\epsilon$.

What do I do now? I tried to use the triangle inequality:

$$|(x_n - a)| -|(y_n -a)| \leq|(x_n - a) -(y_n -a)|=|x_n - y_n - (a-a)| <\epsilon$$

And due to the first inequality ($|x_n - a| <\epsilon$), we can "squeeze it to 0" but I guess that with this inequality, we can't guarantee that we can "squeeze" ($|y_n - a| <\epsilon$) to 0.

Comment: $|y_n-a| = |y_n-x_n + x_n-a| \le |y_n-x_n| + |x_n-a|$

Comment: $|(x-a) + (a-y)| < \epsilon \implies |x-a|+|y-a| < \epsilon$

Comment: Setting $z_n = x_n - y_n$, this reduces to the slightly simpler (and fundamental) fact $ x_n \to a \cap z_n \to b \implies (x_n - z_n) \to a - b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe that for your two bullet points, you should call $n_0$ different things, since there is no guarantee that they're the same for each limit. So we have, for all $\epsilon > 0$, that

- there is an $N_1(\epsilon) \in \mathbb N$ such that $n > N_1 \implies |x_n - a| < \epsilon$, and
- there is an $N_2(\epsilon) \in \mathbb N$ such that $n > N_2 \implies |x_n - y_n| < \epsilon$.

Now all you have to do is note that for $n > N^* = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, \begin{align*}
|y_n - a| &= |(y_n - x_n) + (x_n - a)| \\
&\le |y_n - x_n| + |x_n - a| \quad \text{by the triangle inequality} \\
&\le \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon.
\end{align*}
So $y_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ as required.